# Android Studio not showing logcat for EMULATOR

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, logcat

If I run my app in a device I can see the **logcat** for my app with no problems.

However, When I run the app on the emulator the logcat remains empty. I have changed the device to use emulator:

[image]

The emulator doesn't show actually anything, not only for my app. I enabled the developer mode expecting this to solve the problem but logcat remains empty.

Is there an additional configuration to do?

Comment: IIRC there's a reload button somewhere. I don't remember exactly where, but it should be in the tool window if it still exists. Some times, clicking it fixes a couple issues with non-displaying logcat. No clue why though, or when it works.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this may be a problem with adb inconsistancy. Try restarting it with :

```
adb kill-server && adb start-server
```

Comment: Nope, this does not help.